# PHP/HTML is it possible to make file uploading by user not mandatory

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm making a website where users can apply their cars in form , i choosed to make 10 image inputs because i thought how mobile user could select multiple of photos at once(maybe it's possible but i dont know) so i came with this idea. The problem im facing is that, if one of the uploading inputs are empty it give me an error

Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: Could not access file: in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\TEST\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php:2991 Stack trace: #0 E:\XAMPP\htdocs\TEST\contactform.php(58): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->addAttachment('', '') #1 {main} thrown in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\TEST\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php on line 2991

```
        <label>1 <input type="file" class="file" name="image" id="image" /></label> 
              <label>2 <input type="file" class="file" name="image1" id="image1" /></label> 
              
              <label>3 <input type="file" class="file" name="image2" id="image2" /></label> 
              
              <label>4 <input type="file" class="file" name="image3" id="image3" /></label> 
              
              <label>5 <input type="file" class="file" name="image4" id="image4" /></label> 
              <label>6 <input type="file" class="file" name="image5" id="image5" /></label> 
              <label>7 <input type="file" class="file" name="image6" id="image6" /></label> 
              <label>8 <input type="file" class="file" name="image7" id="image7" /></label> 
              <label>9 <input type="file" class="file" name="image8" id="image8" /></label> 
              <label>10 <input type="file" class="file" name="image9" id="image9" /></label>
```

```
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],
                      $_FILES['image']['name']);
                      
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'],
                      $_FILES['image1']['name']);
                      
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'],
                      $_FILES['image2']['name']);
                      
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'],
                      $_FILES['image3']['name']);
                      
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image4']['tmp_name'],
                      $_FILES['image4']['name']);
                      
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image5']['tmp_name'],
                      $_FILES['image5']['name']);
                      
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image6']['tmp_name'],
                      $_FILES['image6']['name']);
                      
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image7']['tmp_name'],
                      $_FILES['image7']['name']);
                      
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image8']['tmp_name'],
                      $_FILES['image8']['name']);
                      
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image9']['tmp_name'],
                      $_FILES['image9']['name']);
```

Comment: You can use `if isset(<variable>){` to check if each input is selected or not

Comment: Or alternatively just 1 upload and allow selecting multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your file upload to allow multiple images, so you just need one file element.

```
<input type="file" class="file" name="image" id="image" multiple/>
```

Next, just loop through them in your PHP, and add them as an attachment to `$mail`.

```
foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $name) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['image'][$key]['tmp_name'];
    $mail->AddAttachment($tmp_name, $name);
}
```

Comment: This loop gave me this error: 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\TEST\contactform.php on line 57

Comment: @KostasSkutulas Did you submit any files?

Comment: Yes , i did . .